# This automated light system is slowing down randomly

Tags: avr, adc

A PIR sensor sends input to the AVR (ATmega 32A), when input is received and the ADC (LDR) is below a critical value, PB0 is to go high to switch on a relay. A timer counts seconds so that the relay can be turned off after 3 minutes of no PIR signal.

It works, but sometimes it takes a long time to respond, and at random times it is instantaneous. What should I do?

EDIT: I have left the AVCC and AREF pins not connected. Is that a problem?

[image: Schematic]

[image: Picture of setup]
Code:

```
# include <avr/io.h>
# define START 1
# define STOP 0
# define RESET 3
# define TRUE 1
# define FALSE 0
uint8_t seconds=0;

void stopwatch(void)
{   
    seconds=0;
    TCNT1=0;
    TCCR1B |= 1<<CS10|1<<CS11;//timer counter control register started with prescale 64 

}
void InitADC()
{
ADMUX=(1<<REFS0);                         // For Aref=AVcc;
ADCSRA=(1<<ADEN)|(1<<ADPS2)|(1<<ADPS1)|(1<<ADPS0); //Rrescalar div factor =128
}

uint16_t ReadADC(uint8_t ch)
{
   //Select ADC Channel ch must be 0-7
   ch=ch&0b00000111;
   ADMUX|=ch;

   //Start Single conversion
   ADCSRA|=(1<<ADSC);

   //Wait for conversion to complete
   while(!(ADCSRA & (1<<ADIF)));

   //Clear ADIF by writing one to it
   //Note you may be wondering why we have write one to clear it
   //This is standard way of clearing bits in io as said in datasheets.
   //The code writes '1' but it result in setting bit to '0' !!!

   ADCSRA|=(1<<ADIF);

   return(ADC);
}


int main(void)
{   uint16_t adc_result;
    InitADC();
    DDRB=0b00000101;
    PORTB=0b00000000;
    char lightoff=TRUE;
    //stopwatch();
    while (1)
    {
    //adc_result=ReadADC(1);

        //*****clock work***********
            if(TCNT1>15625)
            {
                TCNT1=0;                    
                seconds++;              
            }

        //********************


        if(bit_is_set(PINB,1) && lightoff && ReadADC(1)<700)
        {
            PORTB|=_BV(0);
            lightoff=FALSE;
            stopwatch();        
        }


        if(bit_is_set(PINB,1)&& !lightoff)
        {
            stopwatch();
        }


        if(seconds>180 && !lightoff){
            PORTB&=~_BV(0);
            lightoff=TRUE;
            TCCR1B = 0; // stop clock
            seconds=0;
        }

    }



}
```

EDIT:

The slowing down is not as random as I initially thought. It only responds late if it has been running for a long time without pin B1 getting high from PIR. It is fast if it has been triggered in the last 30 mins at least.

Comment: Add a picture of your set up please.

Comment: could your timer be overflowing after long time?

Comment: @vrleboss the timer part just controls when to switch the relay off, and that part works like clockwork everytime. It only lags when switching on after a long dormant period.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the complete schematics of your setup then there is something missing that might be the cause of the observed behavior:

The decoupling caps. Or more precisely, *the lack of* decoupling capacitors.

Try to put a ~100nF capacitor between GND and Vcc of the ATmega. As close as possible to it's power pin. Voltage spikes, probably from the relay may disturb, reset, or do strange things to your ATmega. And this could be a cause of the observed behavior.

Other hints:

- Check that you have a free wheeling diode connected at your relay input.
- Use a voltage regulator IC to power your ATmega instead of a direct battery connection.

These things would ensure a clean power supply to your ATmega. And this is a good thing. Especially when you use its ADC.

Comment: oh no I use a L7805 for power and there are caps connected to the voltage regulator and to the vcc and gnd of the microcontroller. I did not think that would be relevant so didn't put it in the schematic(first time using the online schematic tool, this much was hard enough)

Comment: diode is also connected at relay input.

Answer (score 0):

`EDIT: I have left the AVCC and AREF pins not connected. Is that a problem?`

`AVcc` is the power supply for the ADC hardware and is independent of `Vcc` unless you written to `ADMUX` to either use external reference voltages or to use an internal reference - which you have.

From the [AtMega32 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8155-8-bit-Microcontroller-AVR-ATmega32A_Datasheet.pdf):

> The ADC has a separate analog supply voltage pin, AVCC. AVCC must not differ more than ±0.3V from VCC.
>   Internal reference voltages of nominally 2.56V or AVCC are provided On-chip. The voltage reference may be externally
>   decoupled at the AREF pin by a capacitor for better noise performance.

You most certainly want to decouple the `Aref` pin with a closely placed decoupling capacitor if you are not supplying a reference voltage here, otherwise this pin is a enormous source of noise - especially on breadboards.

Also, I am pretty certain that you are required to connect `AVcc` to something; I do not think there is any internal switching in which `Vcc` can be shorted to `AVcc`.

I would start by getting the ADC to work properly by ensuring the read values are what you expect. Use a voltage meter and a potentiometer to verify your expecatations. Once that is working then the switching portion is just a bit of code.

Also note that to suppress noise further, you can temporarily shutdown the CPU during sampling. This feature is outlined on page 200 of the datasheet linked above.

Comment: I did test this setup with the same ldr and a lcd. worked fine.

Comment: Either way, you are going to get noisy results without decoupling Aref; the result might be close, but not as close as they could otherwise be. It's right in the datasheet. As for your current setup, it depends on how quickly you were writing to the LCD in your earlier setup. Maybe your sampling was slow enough that what was written to your screen appeared more as an average. If you are sampling more quickly this time then you might be catching those outliers.

Comment: It's really hard to say - I was just making a point about what the datasheet says and what all of the people [here](http://www.avrfreaks.net/) say.

Comment: what does it mean to add a decoupling capacitor to AREF? how much value and between AREF and what?

Comment: I checked voltage in ADC pin, in darkness it is about 0.1 volts and in light 4 volts.

Comment: The (uncoupled) floating pin will effectively act as a antenna picking up noise from the environment. Since this noise becomes superimposed on your reference signal you begin comparing voltages to a faulty node thereby eliciting incorrect results. Adding the coupling capacitor to ground helps to mitigate the problem by providing a lo-impedance pathway to ground.